# Conscious car that takes owners hostage

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am helping a friend search for a short story she read 20+ years ago in junior high. It is about a car that gains a conscious mind and locks the owners in the vehicle and drives and drives and drives. The story is told from the view point of a gas station attendant who sees this car pass year after year.

Anyone know the name of this story?

Comment: Must be the same story described in [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34370/short-sci-fi-story-about-a-car-that-endlessly-drives-itself).

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in [this excellent answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/166264/68872) by [friday13](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/87896/friday13) it seems like this story may be "*[Road Stop](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?72642)*" (1963) by *[David Mason](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?7082)*

> It was like any other car on the road. It was automatic, self-contained - and eternal
> <sub>[Road Stop @ archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/1963-01_IF#page/n91/mode/2up)</sub>